# Any time saving/ short methods to solve this problem?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, ratio

> Three persons A,B,C whose salaries together amount to $144000. Each spend
>   80,85 & 75 percent of their salaries respectively . If their savings
>   are in the ratio 8:9:20, then C's salary is?

This question came of a very strictly timed test and I was wondering the different ways it can be solved and if there was a faster way to do this?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Well apparently the brute force of forming 3 different equations and further operating them. Now that I look at @Bernards's solution I'm thinking why didn't I do this on the test! :(

Answer (score 0):

You can solve quite simply using only basis facts about *proportions*. Denoting $A, B, C$ the respective salaries, we have this information:
$$\frac{0.2A}8=\frac{0.15B}9=\frac{0.25C}{20}\iff \frac A{40}=\frac B{60}=\frac C{80}=\frac{A+B+C}{40+60+80}=\frac{144000}{180}=800$$
whence $C=80\cdot 800=\$\,64000$.

Comment: Dude I think the answer is 64000, The answer you gave weren't even in the options, BTW which are 48000, 64000, 40000 and 32000 .

Comment: @Random Codemonkey: You're right, there was an error in my computation. The answer is corrected now.